# New to Power BI looking for a count of results after applying slicers

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a data set comprised of 4 columns

DateTime(UTC), time(ms), user IP, user ID

I have created slicers for all 4 columns

My goal is to find a way to show a count of how many instances (rows) of data match the criteria based upon the values present in the slicers.

I'd like to just create a box that shows the value for this

I will include a sample of the data. 
I looked through the previous cases but 
was having difficulty trying to turn any related search results into my particular problem.

Please advise and thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to write a measure and drop it in a visual like a card.

```
CountResults = COUNTROWS( TableName )
```

Comment: Interesting. I did this and obtained results I was not expecting. Is this providing an entry to the count for each distinct record?

Comment: It counts the rows after the filters are applied. If you only want distinct rows, then use `COUNTROWS(DISTINCT(TableName))`.

Comment: Thank you ! I  It appears it is working. I had imported time (ms) and it had performed an import with sum. I'm taking that out and it will work. Thank you so kindly!